# Running TBB 7.0.2. How can I change the IP when a site bans me?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ip-address

There used to be an onion icon near the address bar that I could click and change the address but it has gone away. Is there still a way to change the ip address that a site sees when I get banned?

Comment: That should still be there, can you try reinstalling Tor Browser? Have you installed any addons or extensions that may have interfered with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Folow's answer to (re-)add the Tor button, and then:

1. Click the Tor button
2. In the menu that appears, click **New Tor Circuit for this site**.

New Tor Circuit for this site will change the IP address for that website only, but will not require closing all tabs. This option might disrupt other tabs with that same website open, in some cases, but that risk doesn't seem to apply to you.

Answer (score 0):

1. At top-right click on the **3-lines-button** (Humburger button) and select 
   **Customize**.
2. There should be **Torbutton** icon. Drag and drop it to the toolbar.
3. Click on **Exit Customize** green button.
4. On toolbar now Torbutton icon should be visible. Click on the icon and select **New Identity**.

Just a note when you select this option, Tor-browser will close and restart, but current tabs will NOT be preserved. Make sure you can lose current tabs content.